# get html of the same page in c# more than once

Tags: c#, html

I am rendering the same page in HTML with different data in C# and for the second time I am getting this error "A page can have only one server-side Form tag" Here is my code-

```
StringBuilder sbOut = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter swOut = new StringWriter(sbOut);
HtmlTextWriter htwOut = new HtmlTextWriter(swOut);
Page.RenderControl(htwOut);
base.Render(htwOut);
string sOut = sbOut.ToString();
```

Comment: You're not able to have two `<form runat="server"` elements in the same page.

Comment: I am not using <form runat="server"> two times. It is used once only. I am rendering the same page in HTML more than once. for the first time it works fine but for the second. it shows this error. I hope you got it

Comment: Whether you believe me or not, you are rendering it twice. The error explicitly tells you that. I would imagine the HTML is concatenated so you are duplicating the code. In any case, you need to debug your code and see what is *really* in `sOut`. We can't do that for you.

Comment: Sout contains my whole HTML  including the <form></form> but for the next time it again concats the <form></form>  I guess the problem is with base.Render(htwOut);